# 1-Min Countdown Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, timer, countdown, minute

I'm attempting to build a typing test that begins counting down when the user presses a key in the text area. I thought an if-else loop would help display and start the 1-minute countdown timer in my HTML but that's not the case.

Please explain to me what I'm doing wrong & how to correct my code.

HTML:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
<p>Text for typing test will go here.</p>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="14" cols="150" placeholder="Start typing here...">
</textarea>`
```

JS:

```
var seconds=1000 * 60; //1000 = 1 second in JS
var min = seconds * 60;
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea").onkeypress = function() { 
    myFunction()
};
//When a key is pressed in the text area, update the timer using myFunction

function myFunction() {
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = 
     if (seconds>=0) {
         seconds = seconds--;
     } else {
         clearInterval("timer");
         alert("You type X WPM");
     }
} //If seconds are equal or greater than 0, countdown until 1 minute has passed
//Else, clear the timer and alert user of how many words they type per minute

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="0:" + seconds;
```

Comment: you're calling clearInterval, but where do you setInterval? this will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: your min is equal to 1 hour not 1 min.

Comment: `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML =` is invalid syntax; didn't you want to finish this line? What do you want to assign?

Comment: there are syntax errors all over the place.

Comment: @manonthemat I'm assuming that my setInterval should read as follows:
 var aVar = setInterval (function() {  myFunction()}, 1000);

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith thanks for the correction, I've fixed the timing errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are some problems with your solution that I noticed.

1) You clearInterval, but you never setInterval

2) seconds = seconds--, does not do what you think it does because of order of operations in JavaScript.

I modified your JS and have a working solution in this [codepen](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/eJQbGo?editors=1111)

JS:

```
var seconds=60;
var timer;
function myFunction() {
  if(seconds < 60) { // I want it to say 1:00, not 60
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = seconds;
  }
  if (seconds >0 ) { // so it doesn't go to -1
     seconds--;
  } else {
     clearInterval(timer);
     alert("You type X WPM");
  }
}
document.getElementById("textarea").onkeypress = function() {
  if(!timer) {
    timer = window.setInterval(function() { 
      myFunction();
    }, 1000); // every second
  }
} 

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML="1:00";
```

Answer (score 5):

There were lots syntax errors in your code. You need to use `setInterval` function to start the continuous call of your function. More importantly,

```
var seconds = 1000 * 60; //1000 = 1 second in JS
var min = seconds * 60;
```

These calculations were another problem.

`1000 * 60` means `60 seconds`, so `seconds * 60` gives you `60 minutes`.

Like one of the comments said, **`there are syntax errors all over the place.`**. You need to get more insight into coding using JavaScript.

```js
var seconds = 1000 * 60; //1000 = 1 second in JS
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var timer;
textarea.addEventListener("keypress", myFunction)
//When a key is pressed in the text area, update the timer using myFunction

function myFunction() {
   textarea.removeEventListener("keypress", myFunction);
   if(seconds == 60000)
     timer = setInterval(myFunction, 1000)
   seconds -= 1000;
   document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = '0:' + seconds/1000;
   if (seconds <= 0) {
       clearInterval(timer);
       alert("You type X WPM");
   }
} //If seconds are equal or greater than 0, countdown until 1 minute has passed
//Else, clear the timer and alert user of how many words they type per minute

document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML= "0:" + seconds/1000;
```

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
<p>Text for typing test will go here.</p>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="14" cols="150" placeholder="Start typing here...">
</textarea>
```

Comment: what did you change?

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith updating.\

Comment: I like how you handled the timer by recursively calling myFunction and removing the event listener. Good work

Answer (score 1):

I rewrite your code, i think that it ill attempt your needs:

Javascript:

```
var seconds = 0, stop = 60, counterStarted = false, counter;
function myFunction(){
if(counterStarted === false){
counterStarted = true;
counter = setInterval(function(){
    if(seconds <= stop){
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = seconds;
    seconds++;
  }else{
 document.getElementById('textarea').setAttribute("disabled", "disabled");
        clearInterval(counter);
        counterStarted = false;
        seconds = 0;
      }
    },1000)
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="timer"></div>
  <p>
Text for typing test will go here.  </p>
<textarea id="textarea" rows="14" cols="150" placeholder="Start typing here..." onkeypress="myFunction()"></textarea>
```

[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/4swjt345/)

Answer (score 0):

I've put together a small solution for you:

**JavaScript:**

```
    var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea").onkeypress = function(){
        myFunction()
    }
    var totalTime = 10
    var currentTime = totalTime
    var firstTap = true
    var timer = null

    function myFunction() {
        if (firstTap == true){
            firstTap = false
            timer = setInterval(function(){
                currentTime--
                document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentTime;
                if (currentTime < 0){
                    currentTime = totalTime
                    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentTime;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    alert("You type X WPM");
                    firstTap = true
                }
            }, 1000)
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = currentTime
```

The main thing I changed, was that you need to store your timer, and have the callback of your interval be updating your timer display, not the `myFunction()`. Think about it, as you had the code your "timer" `div` would only update when you typed. You want that to update no matter what the user is doing if its a timer.

I put some basic gating logic to detect whether its your first keystroke so you don't start the timer 1000 times, and I just reset it when the alert appears. I also stored the total time at the top and you can set it to whatever value you want. I tested with 10 seconds since I didn't want to wait a minute, but you can move it to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I did this a completely different way since there were so many syntax errors and would not work correctly anyways, see fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rtza7nm0/

```
  var counter = 0;

  function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration,
      minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function() {
      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

      if (--timer < 0) {
        alert("You type " + counter + " WPM");
        timer = duration;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  function myFunction() {
    if (counter == 0) {
      var oneMinute = 60,
        display = document.querySelector('#timer');
      startTimer(oneMinute, display);
      counter++;
    } else {
      counter++;
    }
  };
```